# opengl mipmaps in windows without extensions

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to do this?

I have spend a while manually creating mipmaps through eg.

```
glGenTextures(1, &wall_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, wall_texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 7);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, wall_width1, wall_height1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGB, wall_width2, wall_height2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels2);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 2, GL_RGB, wall_width3, wall_height3, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels3);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, GL_RGB, wall_width4, wall_height4, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels4);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, GL_RGB, wall_width5, wall_height5, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels5);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 5, GL_RGB, wall_width6, wall_height6, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels6);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 6, GL_RGB, wall_width7, wall_height7, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels7);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 7, GL_RGB, wall_width8, wall_height8, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, wall_pixels8);
```

because `glGenerateMipmap` was unavailable to me.

I coded the above on Mac (in a multi platform toolkit) and then migrated it to Windows and now find that  `GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` and `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` are both 'undeclared identifiers.

This is quite annoying. As it stands loading different texture levels works (all the following lines are fine), but without being able to tell opengl which ones to use the texture doesn't render. Surely there is a way to specify these if I can actually set the texture levels in the same supported version of OpenGL?

Comment: Well, anything beyond OpenGL-1.1 must be accessed through extensions in Windows. If you just want to use new tokens getting a fairly recent `glext.h` from http://opengl.org/registry and including that in addition would do the trick.